# static constexpr chrono as struct member

Tags: c++, arrays, c++11, constexpr, c++-chrono

I have an interface header with a struct like looks like this (**C++11**):

```
// header
struct MyStruct
{
    std::chrono::milliseconds time_1{defaultTime};
    std::chrono::milliseconds time_2{defaultTime};
    std::chrono::milliseconds time_3{defaultTime};

    // default value
    static constexpr std::chrono::milliseconds defaultTime{5000};
};

// cpp
constexpr std::chrono::milliseconds MyStruct::defaultTime;

int main()
{
    MyStruct ms{};
}
```

Everything is fine with GCC and MSVC, the problem is that on Clang 9 I get this error:
`Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64: "MyStruct::defaultTime":`

I want to avoid code duplication and to keep that `defaultTime{5000}` visible to my library users in the header. But it should compile on Clang 9 also.

An alternative would be this, although I don't really like to default to be the first member there:

```
// header
struct MyStruct
{
    // default value
    const std::chrono::milliseconds defaultTime{5000};

    std::chrono::milliseconds time_1{defaultTime};
    std::chrono::milliseconds time_2{defaultTime};
    std::chrono::milliseconds time_3{defaultTime};
}
```

Any alternatives? thanks

Comment: I understand you specifically called out C++11 but it's worth mentioning: The "trivial" answer is to move on to C++17 (or above) and remove the definition of `MyStruct::defaultTime` from the cpp file.

Comment: I know, it's not trivial to move to C++17 when working in a company. :-), I know that `inline` would have saved me.

Comment: Note, your alternative is pretty bad as the `defaultTime` will be included in every single instance of `MyStruct`.

Answer (score 1):

In C++11, an easy fix is to use a function instead of a straight value. It's not as clean as the syntax you want, but scoped typed constants are just one of those things that only got sorted out more recently.

```cpp
#include <chrono>

struct MyStruct
{
    std::chrono::milliseconds time_1{defaultTime()};
    std::chrono::milliseconds time_2{defaultTime()};
    std::chrono::milliseconds time_3{defaultTime()};

    static constexpr std::chrono::milliseconds defaultTime() {
        return std::chrono::milliseconds{5000};
    }
};
```

Works fine on all three main compilers in C++11:
https://gcc.godbolt.org/z/9W9Wojhvh

> I was using that defaultTime to silence a clang-tidy readability-magic-numbers,

If you don't actually need the constant to be strongly typed, and since this is an integer, using an enum is a classic way of tackling scoped integer constants:

```cpp
#include <chrono>

struct MyStruct
{
    std::chrono::milliseconds time_1{defaul_time_ms};
    std::chrono::milliseconds time_2{defaul_time_ms};
    std::chrono::milliseconds time_3{defaul_time_ms};

    enum {
      defaul_time_ms = 5000
    };
};
```

Comment: thanks, btw, my original code compiles also on godbolt, but not on my computer, when using 2 files (header + cpp). I was using that `defaultTime` to silence a clang-tidy `readability-magic-numbers`, unfortunately using this new function, that 5000 is a magic number again. any way to trick it, without adding a new variable into the function? thanks

Comment: @taw good call, I've changed the godbolt link to include fully linked versions of the code. It works.

Comment: Nice tricks, thanks Frank, I was trying to use `static constexpr int defaultTime{5000};` hoping that it will work, but it does not. https://gcc.godbolt.org/z/q1dcxzjhY